# Can't find WinWindow by property "Name"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I've got the following problem:

I try to create a Coded UI Test in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition without using the Generator. I want to achieve the very simple thing of pressing a button and looking at the results.
My Forms are not directly WinForms, but it's the basis of them.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public void CodedUITestTestMethod()
    {
        //1. Step: Log into the program
        LogIntoProgram();
    }

private void LogIntoProgram()
    {
        // Find the Login-Window
        WinWindow loginWindow = GetWindowByTitle("Program - Login");

        [...]
    }

private WinWindow GetWindowByName(string title, UITestControl parent = null)
    {
        // If the Window has a parent, assign it to the window
        WinWindow result = parent == null ? new WinWindow() : new WinWindow(parent);

        result.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, title);

        result.Find();

        return result;
    }
```

The [...] section is where I want to press the button. The problem occurs before that though, as I can't even find the window I'm looking for. It repeatedly throws the UITestControlNotFound exception, no matter if I use the Title or the Classname of the Form.
I got the feeling that I am missing a very major point, but I can't figure out which one.

Thanks for the help in advance,

SchwarzSkills :)

Comment: Have you tried a [partial name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086713/finding-a-window-when-only-part-of-the-window-title-is-known-in-coded-ui-tests)?

Comment: @lloyd Did that just now, played around with it a bit, but it didn't really help, I'm afraid :/

Comment: Why are you setting the UITestControl parent to null ?

Comment: try using both class name and name, are u sure your object's type is WinWIndow?

Comment: @lloyd I've set the partent to null, as it doesn't have one yet. It is a completely new started application and the window I'm trying to reach is the first one to load. I tried to set the parent to the Desktop as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Working examples I can find all require the [parent to be set](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/03/build-a-coded-ui-test-without-a-ui-map/) Forms or [Websites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/02/12/hand-coding-a-coded-ui-test.aspx). My experience with them is the parent must be set. when you running in debug mode is the parent set or null?

Comment: @barakcaf I'm pretty sure it has to be WinWindow, unless I completely miss what a WinWindow is supposed to be. I thought of it as the Form to include the other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your [application and pass it into the WinWindow](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/03/build-a-coded-ui-test-without-a-ui-map/)

```
     var app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch("C:\\Windows\\System32\\myProgram.exe"
, "%windir%\\System32\\myProgram.exe");

    WinWindow loginWindow = GetWindowByTitle("Program - Login", app);
```

Comment: I think this is the right solution to the basic problem, so I'll mark it as such. Didn't help me though, because my Program has other issues with the Coded UI Testing solution from Visual Studio. Thank for the help anyways :)

Comment: NP. Please post your other issues as new question(s). Try using the Coded UI Test recorder for UI Map generation. If it is successful, you can grab the search properties off it.